# How does ROS calculates the actual robot path?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am interested in knowing how does ROS determines the actual path traversed by the robot. What is the mathematics behind it. I could get some answer following hector_trajectory package but in Rviz there is an option robot_path. How to get accurate trajectory of the path followed by robot?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190028/how-does-ros-calculates-the-actual-robot-path?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
Are you interested in the path that was driven by the robot or the path that the robot plans to drive?

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2014-08-13**:
The path that was driven by the robot. I understand how the robot_pose_ekf can be used to correct the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Extract from [base_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner) wiki

ROS path planning is based on `Trajectory Rollout` and `Dynamic Window Approach (DWA)` algorithms which are proposed in below papers.

[Brian P. Gerkey and Kurt Konolige. "Planning and Control in Unstructured Terrain ".](http://www.cs.washington.edu/ai/Mobile_Robotics/postscripts/colli-ieee.ps.gz) Discussion of the Trajectory Rollout algorithm in use on the LAGR robot.

[D. Fox, W. Burgard, and S. Thrun. "The dynamic window approach to collision avoidance".](http://www.cs.washington.edu/ai/Mobile_Robotics/postscripts/colli-ieee.ps.gz) The Dynamic Window Approach to local control.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0